# How to Delete Comment from Post on Node, express and Mongoose and Ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, mongoose

Please i need help on how to delete a single comment from a Post. when i click delete it return `500 error`. some of the things that are confusing me here is, if i pass both post and comment ids on the link, how will i tell Ajax that this one is for post and this one is for comment.
Here is my posts schema

```
 const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
       type: String,
       required: true
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
   from: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   createdAt: { 
     required: true, 
     default: Date.now
  },
  postImage: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]

 })
```

here is my ajax from main.js file.

```
/deleting comment with Ajax
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.delete-comment').on('click', function(e) {
    const $target = $(e.target);
    const id = $target.attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/posts/comments/'+id,
        success: function(response) {
            window.location.href='/posts';
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
  }); 
});
```

my routes/comments

```
//Delete comment inside a post
router.delete( '/comments/:id', function( req, res ){
  const post = Post.findOne({_id: req.params.postId});
  const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  let query = {_id:new ObjectId(req.params.id)}
  console.log(query)

  post.comments.delete(query, function(err) {
    if(err){
     console.log(err);
   }
   res.send('Success');
 });
})
```

my views/index.ejs

```
 //Comments and link
<% const counter = post.comments.length >= 2 ? "Comments" : "Comment"; %>
<button class="show-comments"><%= post.comments.length + " " + counter + "" %></button>
<% %>
<div class="postcomments" ><% post.comments.forEach(item => { %>
  <ul >
    <li><%= item.description %></li>
    <a class="delete-comment" href="#" data-id="<%=item._id%>">Delete</a>

 </ul>
<% });%>
```

my app.js

```
//use route from app.js 
var commentRouter = require('./routes/comments');
app.use('/posts', commentRouter);
```

here is what is being returned on my terminal

```
DELETE /posts/comments/5e8ad7121277855e656b3379 500 5.395 ms - 3698
```

Comment: How we will know which comment do you want to delete? You need boht postId and commentId for this? Also can you add your post schema to the question and sample document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know both the postId and the commentId to be able to delete the comment from posts collection. Also it would be good to delete the comment inside the comments collection.

So change your delete route to include postId and commentId as req.params.
You can delete a comment from posts using the `findByIdAndUpdate` method and `$pull` operator.

```js
router.delete("/comments/:postId/:commentId", async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.postId,
      {
        $pull: { comments: req.params.commentId },
      },
      { new: true }
    );

    if (!post) {
      return res.status(400).send("Post not found");
    }

    await Comment.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.commentId);

    res.send("Success");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

**TEST**

Let's say we have this post document with 3 comments.

Posts:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b10c49ae619486094ed10"),
    "comments" : [
        ObjectId("5e8b104f9ae619486094ed0d"),
        ObjectId("5e8b10599ae619486094ed0e"),
        ObjectId("5e8b105e9ae619486094ed0f")
    ],
    "title" : "Title",
    "description" : "Description...",
    "from" : "From",
    "postImage" : "Post Image",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-04-06T14:21:40.884+03:00")
}
```

Comments:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b105e9ae619486094ed0f"),
    "message" : "Comment 3"
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b10599ae619486094ed0e"),
    "message" : "Comment 2"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b104f9ae619486094ed0d"),
    "message" : "Comment 1"
}
```

If we want to delete the comment with `_id:5e8b10599ae619486094ed0e`, we need to send a DELETE request to our route using url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/comments/5e8b10c49ae619486094ed10/5e8b10599ae619486094ed0e
```

`5e8b10c49ae619486094ed10` is the postId, `5e8b10599ae619486094ed0e` is the commentId.

Result will be like this:

Posts:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b10c49ae619486094ed10"),
    "comments" : [
        ObjectId("5e8b104f9ae619486094ed0d"),
        ObjectId("5e8b105e9ae619486094ed0f")
    ],
    "title" : "Title",
    "description" : "Description...",
    "from" : "From",
    "postImage" : "Post Image",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-04-06T14:21:40.884+03:00")
}
```

Comments:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b105e9ae619486094ed0f"),
    "message" : "Comment 3"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8b104f9ae619486094ed0d"),
    "message" : "Comment 1"
}
```

Comment: @SuleymanSahThank you so much for taking your time to explain to me how it works, i really appreciate it. I did exactly what you said with the code you gave me above, and changed my link to include post id like this ` <a class="delete-comment" href="#" data-id="<%=post.id%>/<%=item._id%>">Delete</a> ` and everything is

Comment: I know i am a bit late to the party, but, isn't there a more efficient way of doing this? Like for esxample using the .pre method on the schema so you don't have to do this every time you remove a comment from a post?

Comment: @Matias yes it is possible, but I don't think it will be more efficient. We need a database access in that case too.

Comment: @SuleymanSah gotcha, so, I am trying to do this, and it's deleting my comment, but i am getting an error here: $pull: { comments: req.params.commentId }, to fix it, i did this: $pull: { comments: {_id: req.params.commentId }}, and no more error, but, it doesn't take it out of the array. Is it possible that this solution doesnt work anymore?, also, I'm using typescript

Comment: @Matias better to ask a new question about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your nodejs/express route contains this code. Maybe it should do more with possible errors: specifically, pass the error to the `next()` function that's the third parameter of any route handler.

```
post.comments.delete(query, function(err) {
    if(err){
         console.log(err)
         return next(err)
     }
     res.send('Success')
});
```

Passing an error value to `next()` should deliver the error message to the user.  And, you have the same message showing up on your server's console.log.  So if the error is from there you should learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem Except that before erasing the post, I want to make sure that the user deleting the post is the creator of the same post. My data set is a little bit different.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    comment: { type: String, required: true },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    imagePost: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

const stationSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    nameUnit: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    typeOfPoint: { type: String },
    image: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    lat: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    long: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },

    // Base
    nameBase: { type: String, required: true },
    element: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    baseCommanderInfo: { type: String },
    aboutBaseInfo: { type: String },

    // Unit
    unitSuperviserInfo: { type: String },
    unitCommanderInfo: { type: String },
    unitInfo: { type: String },
    taskInfo: { type: String },
    benefitInfo: { type: String },

    // address
    country: { type: String },
    province: { type: String },
    town: { type: String },
    adresse: { type: String },
    postalCode: { type: String },

    posts: [postSchema],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

const Station = mongoose.model('Station', stationSchema)

export default Station
```

NodeControler

```
const removeStationPost = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const stationId = req.params.id
  const postId = req.params.idPost
  const userId = req.user._id

  console.log(stationId)
  console.log(postId)
  console.log(userId)

  const station = await Station.findById(stationId)

  if (station) {
    station.posts.pull(postId)
    await station.save()
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Post removed' })
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('Post not found')
  }
})
```

So now everybody can delete anybody else post with Postman